# How to make a PHP structure, that doesn't complain about requests of undefined properties?

Tags: php

I have a bunch of optional settings and I'm sick of checking for `isset` and `property_exists`.

In Laravel, if I ask for a property that does not exist on a model or request, I get `null` and no complaints (errors). How can I do the same for my data structure.

If I try array, I can't do simple `$settings['setting13']`, I have to either pre-fill it all with nulls or do `isset($settings['setting13']) ? $settings['setting13'] : ''` or `$settings['setting13'] ?? null`. If I try an object (`new \stdClass()`), `$settings->setting13` still gives me a warning of Undefined property.

How can I make a class such that it responds `null` or an empty string whenever it is asked for a property that it doesn't have?

Comment: With objects you can implement the magic __call / __get methods in your object to do those checks for you, and implement the arrayaccess interface to allow array access.

Comment: What is your structure in where you would ever request a variable that doesn't exist?

Comment: @JonStirling Thanks for the keywords, now I found how Laravel models do that. Is this somehow doable without defining a class explicitly? I need this in one place, but it seems that `stdClass` does not support magic methods.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Simplified example - text fields on a form. I need to fill those if they're set by various means (GET query, user preferences). So I grab stuff from GET, add some stuff for specific fields and in the view I set `name="field5" value="<? $values->field5 ?>"` for the text fields. I'd really like to avoid checks there.

Comment: You're correct, it won't work with stdClass you have to use your own classes as it appears you've found in Laravel. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do what Laravel does, create a class that deals with your data structure which returns a value if key exists, and something else if it doesn't.

I'll illustrate with an example class (this class supports the "dot notation" of accessing array keys):

```
class MyConfigClass
{
    protected $data;

    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function get($path = '', $default = null)
    {
        if(!is_string($path))
        {
            return $default;
        }


        // There's a dot in the path, traverse the array
        if(false !== strpos('.', $path))
        {
            // Find the segments delimited by dot
            $segments = explode('.', $path);

            $result = $this->data;

            foreach($segments as $segment)
            {
                if(isset($result[$segment]))
                {
                    // We have the segment
                    $result = $result[$segment];
                }
                else
                {
                    // The segment isn't there, return default value
                    return $default;
                }
            }

            return $result;
        }

        // The above didn't yield a result, check if the key exists in the array and if not - return default
        return isset($this->data[$path]) ? $this->data[$path] : $default;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
$my_structure = [
    'url' => 'www.stackoverflow.com',
    'questions' => [
        'title' => 'this is test title'
    ]
];

$config = new MyConfigClass($my_structure);

echo $config->get('url'); // echoes www.stackoverflow.com
echo $config->get('questions.title'); // echoes this is test title
echo $config->get('bad key that is not there'); // returns null
```

Answer (score 2):

```
!empty($settings['setting13']) ? $settings['setting13'] : ''
```

can be replaced with

```
$settings['setting13'] ?: ''
```

as long as whatever you want to print and whatever you want to check exists is the same expression. It's not the cleanest thing ever - which would be to check the existence of anything - but it's reasonably clear and can be chained :

```
echo ($a ?: $b ?: $c ? $default ?: '');
```

However, you are not the first who are "sick of checking for `isset` and `property_exists`, it's just that we still have to do it, or else we get unexpected results when we expect it the least.

**It's not about saving time typing code, it's about saving time not debugging.**

EDIT : As pointed in the comments, I wrote the first line with `isset()` instead of `!empty()`. Since `?:` returns the left operand if it's equal to `true`, it's of course uncompatible with unchecked variables, you have at least to check for existence beforehand. It's emptiness that can be tested.
The operator that returns its left operand if it exists and is different from `NULL` is `??`, which can be chained the same way `?:` does.

Comment: I have no problem doing this in "pure" PHP files. But in views - to repeat the checks in every text input... it seems so ugly and damaging the readability  Workaround is to prefill all the possible array keys with `null`s seem to introduce more breaking points...

Comment: It's no black magic at all, just syntaxic sugar that puts the same expression both before and after the `?`. Keep that in mind since it only works with scalars. Array entires and object properties will still require you to use a function to check for existence.

Comment: While I personally prefer the longer syntax because, to me, that shortcut is unintuitive and would take a moment to read and understand... I'm upvoting just for that last bolded statement.  I wish I could upvote that statement twice.

Comment: @David I mostly use it in views where I print a lot of strings that may be empty. That's in fact the only case where I find it both readable and safe enough to be efficient since it allows me to refrain PHP verbosity from making my views messy without losing safety. In pute PHP code, these shortcuts are definitely bad manners.

Comment: `?:` does ***not*** suppress warnings about non-existing indices! The only operator that does that is `??`.

Comment: @deceze Exactly. That's not to be employed with arrays, that's why I specified to only use it with scalars.

Comment: Well, your very first sentence is incorrect; `isset($a) ? $a : $b` is *not* equivalent to `$a ?: $b` and can't simply be replaced; scalar or no scalar.

Comment: @deceze Damn, you are right, I was thinking about `empty()` instead ! Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Same thing with `empty` really.

Comment: It doesn't replace `!empty` if it's used to also check for existence, but `?:` returns its right operand if the left one is evaluates to `''`, `false` or `null`.

Comment: This answer is still telling an untruth.   `!empty() ? ... : ...` is not the same thing as `... ?: ...`

Answer (score 2):

There is also a possibility to create wrapper as  Jon Stirling mentioned in a comments. This approach will allow to keep code clean and also add functionality via inheritance.

```
<?php
class myArray implements ArrayAccess {
    private $container; 

    function __construct($myArray){
        $this->container = $myArray;
    }
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
    }

}

$settings = array("setting1"=>1,"setting2"=>2,"setting3"=>3);

$arr = new myArray($settings);

echo $arr['setting1'];
echo "<br>";
echo $arr['setting3'];
echo "<br>";
echo $arr['setting2'];
echo "<br>";
echo "------";
echo "<br>";
echo  $arr['setting4'] ?:"Value is null";
```

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly not the best way to do this, but you can use the error suppressor in php like this:

`$value = @$settings['setting13'];`

This will quitely set`$value` to `NULL` if `$settings['setting13']` is not set and not report the undefined variable notice.

As for objects, you should just calling for attributes that are not defined in class.